# Calling different session beans in same or remote Machine in EJB 2.1

Tags: ejb

Iam using ejb 2.1 stateless session beans in my application.I already implemented some common busineess methods i.e.,ABSessionBean.java.Today i got new requirment,So i implemented a new session bean i.e.,ADSessionbean.So i need to use that common bussiness methods from ABSessionBean.java.How to call ABSessionBean.java method in ADSessionbean?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to call public method defined in same session bean.

This might help you

```
ITestLocal local = (ITestLocal)_ctx.getEJBLocalObject();
local.method();
```

Where `_ctx` is the `javax.ejb.SessionContext` initialize within `setSessionContext` method of session bean.